# Floating effect on ui controls in TableViewCell using Autolayout

Tags: ios7, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Three buttons are needed to be put on a table view cell as shown in the attached image. 
[image]
Using Autolayout I can manage to adjust them to be displaying appropriately using compression or expansion etc. But for really small devices like 3.5 inch or iphone4 or 5 etc the size is really not able to come in one line.
How do we split them in multi lines using AutoLayout (similar to floating in css) for such devices in portrait orientation as for landscaped display or bigger devices they fit only in one line?

Is there any possible way of fixing this issue without redesigning the controls placements etc.?